# What does "EW(Hα)" mean?

Tags: astrophysics, star-formation

I came across a website saying that classical T Tauris have an "EW(Hα) > 5 angstroms".

Does anybody know what "EW" means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"EW" stands for Equivalent Width. The equivalent width of a spectral line is essentially the range of continuum one would integrate over to get the same flux as the spectral line.

In your case, this is the Hα line.

Comment: +1, but for future readers, the formula would be nice :)

Comment: I agree with you, @pela. It would be nice to have a formula to back it up.